# Type hinting when multiple types are in input and output but in 1-to-1 relation between them

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have the following code:

```
 AnyTypeEnum = TypeVar("AnyTypeEnum", Type[Enum], Type[IntEnum])
 AnyEnum = TypeVar("AnyEnum", Enum, IntEnum)

 def decode(value: str, enum_class: AnyTypeEnum) -> AnyEnum:
     return make_map(enum_class)[value]

 @functools.cache()
 def make_map(enum_class: AnyTypeEnum) -> Dict[str, AnyEnum]:
     return {x.name: x for x in enum_class}
```

If I pass an IntEnum class, I'll have in output IntEnum values, same with Enum. The mix from a class to the values of the other one is never possible.

Yet, mypy reports the erros:

1.Line 9: dictionary comprehension has incompatible type Enum, expected IntEnum

2.Line 9: dictionary comprehension has incompatible type IntEnum, expected Enum

I'm using TypeVar to solve the problem of "type mixing" between input and output that is present if I use Union instead, but apparently it's not completely fixed.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nothing binding your output and input types. At the moment they're entirely unrelated. Try this

```
AnyEnum = TypeVar("AnyEnum", Enum, IntEnum)

def decode(value: str, enum_class: Type[AnyEnum]) -> AnyEnum:
    return make_map(enum_class)[value]

@functools.cache()
def make_map(enum_class: Type[AnyEnum]) -> Dict[str, AnyEnum]:
    return {x.name: x for x in enum_class}
```

Alternatively, `@overload` should work.

Comment: This works. For future readers the solution I've chosen is identical to this one but I replaced AnyEnum definition with TypeVar("AnyEnum", bound=Enum), which is a better choice for my purpose since in this way AnyEnum can be Enum or any class deriving from it (which also includes IntEnum).